# solving equation in python with SymPy takes forever

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I tried to solve this equation but still running.
I gave the symbol and the equation is "Eq((1-(1+ x )**(-60))/ x+32*(1+x)**(-60) , 41.81)".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `solve` and `solveset` usual work is to split an expression into numerator and denominator, and return solutions for the one that are not in the other.

Let's define a helper function to put the solutions from `nsolve` into a `FiniteSet` and one to give the final solution:

```
>>> from sympy import FiniteSet, nsolve, Add, Eq
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> rr = lambda x: FiniteSet(*[i[0] for i in real_roots(x, multiple=False)])
>>> sol = lambda n, d: list(rr(n) - rr(d))
>>> go = lambda eq: sol(*eq.rewrite(Add).as_numer_denom())
```

Now we try this out on your original expression:

```
>>> eq = Eq(32/(x + 1)**60 + (1 - 1/(x + 1)**60)/x, 41.81)
>>> fsol = go(eq)  # very slow
>>> [i.n(3) for i in fsol]
[-3.33, -2.56, -1.44, -0.568, -0.228, 0.0220]
```

If you check those out by substituting into the original expression (written as an expression) you will find that only the last one is valid

```
>>> expr = eq.rewrite(Add)
>>> [expr.subs(x, i).n(3) for i in fsol]
[-42.1, -42.2, 4.72e+22, 2.64e+23, 1.97e+8, 1.31e-15]
```

Now let's replace that Float with a Rational and get solutions:

```
>>> req = nsimplify(eq, rational=True); req
Eq(32/(x + 1)**60 + (1 - 1/(x + 1)**60)/x, 4181/100)
>>> rsol = go(_)  # pretty fast
>>> [i.n(3) for i in rsol]
[-2.00, 0.0220]
```

We know the 2nd solution is right; let's check the first:

```
>>> req.subs(x, rsol[0]).rewrite(Add).n(3)
-0.e-114
```

So both solutions appear to be valid and you don't get any spurious solutions which (by the way) I wasn't expecting from `nsolve`.

Answer (score 1):

An exact analytic solution to this is unlikely but you can get numeric solutions e.g.:

```
In [18]: nsolve(eq, x, -2)
Out[18]: -1.99561339048822
```

Since this can be transformed into a polynomial you can find all real solutions like:

```
In [20]: p = Poly(nsimplify(eq).rewrite(Add).as_numer_denom()[0])

In [21]: [r[0].n() for r in p.real_roots(multiple=False)]
Out[21]: [-1.99561339048822, -1.0, 0, 0.0219988833527669]
```

Using `as_numer_denom` like this can potentially introduce spurious solutions though so you should check them (e.g. by plotting the function around each root). For example `0` is not actually a root.